# Display Map Of Route In HERE maps

Tags: routes

Does anyone know how I can get a map of a route in HERE maps?

I can get the route details but am unsure how to display this on a map. 
The documentation mentions a "RouteID" but it's not clear where to get this. 
There is no "RouteID" in the response when I get a route.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
MapRoute mMapRoute = new MapRoute(route);
mMapRoute.setColor(routeColor);
mMap.addMapObject(mMapRoute);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!